# Docker-Nginx unexpected redirects (304)

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I’m having trouble with `docker-compose` and `nginx`. First, I have this `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    depends_on:
      - web
      - api

  web:
    build: ./web
    depends_on:
      - api

  api:
    build: ./api
```

Both `web` (port 3000) and `api` (port 8000) are express servers that return **WEB** and **API** respectively. Now, inside `./nginx`:

```
# Dockefile

FROM nginx:alpine

COPY ["default.conf", "/etc/nginx/conf.d/"]

EXPOSE 80





# default.conf

server {
  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://web:3000;
  }

  location /api {
    proxy_pass  http://api:8000;
  }
}
```

Now, when I go to http://localhost:8080, I get **WEB**, but when I go to http://localhost:8080/api, it redirects to http://localhost:1337/api/ and I get nothing (by the way, it throws a 304 error)

However, when I write this default.conf (put `api` in `/`)

```
# default.conf

server {
  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://api:8000;
  }

  location /api {
    proxy_pass  http://web:3000;
  }
}
```

I get the same result but in `/` I get **API**, so both servers work.

Comment: how to you config port which api listen on  ? 1337 is default api port ?

Comment: the api container has `EXPOSE 8000` and the express server is listening to the port 8000

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it helps you or not. I am using nginx docker image directly in my docker-compose.

for example.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  jobsaf-server:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.production
    container_name: jobsaf-server
    ports:
     - "3000:3000"
     - "5858:5858"
     - "35729:35729"
     - "6379:6379"
    environment:
     - NODE_ENV=production
    networks:
      - front-tier
      - back-tier
    depends_on:
      - "redis"
      - "mongo"
    links:
      - mongo
      - redis
    volumes:
     - ./server:/var/www/app/jobsaf-website/server
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable
    depends_on:
      - jobsaf-server
    links:
      - jobsaf-server
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf  
    ports:
     - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo
    volumes:
      - "db-data:/data/db"
    environment: 
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${DB_USER}
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=admin
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:27017:27017"
    networks:
      - back-tier
  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    networks:
      - back-tier   
volumes:
  db-data:
    # - /data/db
networks:
  front-tier:
  back-tier:
```

Comment: So, you are binding the jobsaf-server's ports to the host machine (that works for me), but I want to use only the internal network provided by docker-compose.